# What does the number of " single-word instructions " mean on a MCU's memory specifications?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, memory

I have copied the following sentence from a PIC MCU datasheet:

"PIC18(L)F26K22, PIC18(L)F46K22: 64 Kbytes of Flash Memory, **up to 37,768 single-word instructions**."

the question is what does " 37,768 single-word instructions" mean for a memory ?

does it show how fast is the memory or something else ? what's its meaning and how is it calculated ?

Comment: First of all, it's 32,768 words, and it's a measure of the memory size, not speed.

Comment: By the way, according to international standard the size of the Flash would correctly be described as 64 kibibytes or 64 KiB. The prefix kibi means 2^10 while kilo means 10^3.

Comment: I guess it's this datasheet:  https://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/picmicro_sg/documents/devicedoc/cn547043.pdf It does actually contain the 37768 figure (page 64, section 5.1), so technically the quote here is correct. It's obviously a typo, though, there's the correct number in table 1 on page 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your question contains a typo, you mean 32,768 (2^15) not 37,768.

The PIC in question has a 16-bit instruction word.

The flash memory size is specified as 64K (65536) *bytes*.  With two bytes per word, that is space for 32768 simple instructions.

Many processors, apparently including this one, offer instructions of varying length - more complex instructions may include things like immediate operands or memory addresses.  These take more bits to encode, and so are longer than the "single-word" instructions.

The data sheet is thus giving you a best case.  Depending on the compiler or hand coding strategy, actual code might have varying average instruction length, so it is harder to say how many *typical* instructions could fit in flash.  Even if it's possible to write a program using all single-word instructions, on a machine designed to support them it may well be more efficient to use some multi-word ones, especially if that avoids needing to go do another fetch of a constant from data memory.

Comment: Did you mean "immediate operands"?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that it should be **32,768** single-word instructions. If a "word" is two bytes and the memory has 65,536 bytes then the memory can hold 32,768 such words. It doesn't have anything to do with the speed of the memory.